# Unwanted Duplicate Triangle when selecting a Triangle from Mesh with Barycentric Selection. - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, triangulation, vertices

What I'm trying to do is select a specific triangle on any given mesh, so I'm using the Barycentric algorithm. However, as seen [here, there are some strange behaviors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FoEaA64v4lY) at certain locations and always an unwanted second triangle. Best guess, it has something to do with inaccurate float precision of the Vector3.

---

Here is the Script I'm Currently Using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpecificTriangleIndex : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera m_camera;
    public LayerMask layermask;

    public Vector3[] vertices;
    public Vector3[] normals;
    public int[] triangles;

    public List<int> triangleIndices = new List<int>(); ///Returned Triangle Indices -- What it thinks is selected.
    public List<Vector3> baryAllens = new List<Vector3>(); ///Position of Verticies of Returned Triangles

    private RaycastHit hit;
    private Transform objectHit;
    private Vector3 bary;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            EobardThawne();
            Raycast();
        }
    }
    void Raycast()
    {
        Ray ray = m_camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, layermask))
        {
            objectHit = hit.transform;
            MeshFilter meshFilter = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
            Mesh mesh = meshFilter.sharedMesh;
            vertices = mesh.vertices;
            normals = mesh.normals;
            triangles = mesh.triangles;

            Vector3 p = transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point);
            for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i += 3)
            {
                Vector3 a = vertices[triangles[i]];
                Vector3 b = vertices[triangles[i + 1]];
                Vector3 c = vertices[triangles[i + 2]];

                bary = GetBarycentric(a, b, c, p);
                if (InTriangle(bary))
                {
                    triangleIndices.Add(i / 3);
                    baryAllens.Add(a + objectHit.position);
                    baryAllens.Add(b + objectHit.position);
                    baryAllens.Add(c + objectHit.position);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < baryAllens.Count; i += 3)
            {
                Vector3 v0 = baryAllens[i];
                Vector3 v1 = baryAllens[i + 1];
                Vector3 v2 = baryAllens[i + 2];

                Debug.DrawLine(v0, v1, Color.green);
                Debug.DrawLine(v1, v2, Color.green);
                Debug.DrawLine(v2, v0, Color.green);
            }
        }
    }

    Vector3 GetBarycentric(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2, Vector2 v3, Vector2 p)
    {
        Vector3 B = new Vector3();
        B.x = ((v2.y - v3.y) * (p.x - v3.x) + (v3.x - v2.x) * (p.y - v3.y)) /
            ((v2.y - v3.y) * (v1.x - v3.x) + (v3.x - v2.x) * (v1.y - v3.y));
        B.y = ((v3.y - v1.y) * (p.x - v3.x) + (v1.x - v3.x) * (p.y - v3.y)) /
            ((v3.y - v1.y) * (v2.x - v3.x) + (v1.x - v3.x) * (v2.y - v3.y));
        B.z = 1 - B.x - B.y;
        return B;
    }

    bool InTriangle(Vector3 barycentric)
    {
        return (barycentric.x >= 0.0f) && (barycentric.x <= 1.0f)
            && (barycentric.y >= 0.0f) && (barycentric.y <= 1.0f)
            && (barycentric.z >= 0.0f); //(barycentric.z <= 1.0f)
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(hit.point, .01f);

        Gizmos.color = Color.cyan;
        foreach (int i in triangleIndices)
        {
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(FindCenter(i * 3), .01f);
            Debug.DrawLine(hit.point, FindCenter(i * 3), Color.red);
        }
    }

    public void EobardThawne()
    {
        triangleIndices.Clear();
        baryAllens.Clear();
    }

    public Vector3 FindCenter(int i)
    {
        Vector3 v0 = transform.TransformPoint(vertices[triangles[i]]);
        Vector3 v1 = transform.TransformPoint(vertices[triangles[i + 1]]);
        Vector3 v2 = transform.TransformPoint(vertices[triangles[i + 2]]);
        Vector3 center = (v0 + v1 + v2) / 3;
        return center;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want only one triangle anyway then why is this even an array?

Comment: Anyway instead of calculating this yourself why not rather use the proper mesh in a mesh collider and then simply use the already provided [`RaycastHit.triangleIndex`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-triangleIndex.html)?

Comment: @derHugo The reason its an array is because the correct triangle index could have been one of the two values: One that I wanted, and one that I didn't. When I used a break, it would display either the right or the wrong triangle. I made it an array to catch both as a debug measure.

And RaycastHit.triangleIndex does not work for my purposes. It always returns -1. Apparently, this is due to convex mesh.

Comment: This is not due to convex mesh but because your objects don't use a `MeshCollider` but a `CapsuleCollider`

Comment: I would like this to work with any colliders, not just MeshColliders. Say, if a ragdoll is using CapsuleColliders for physics.

Comment: Honestly though, the reason I abandoned trying to get [RaycastHit.triangleIndex](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-triangleIndex.html) working so fast is because I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYAgJN3x4GA) video, and thought it would be cool to try to implement it. 

If there is a better/ less convoluted solution that I'm just missing to have RaycastHit.triangleIndex work with all colliders, I would very much like to know.

Comment: @derHugo I did finally get RaycastHit.triangleIndex to work by adding a MeshCollider to the GameObject and just raycasting that. For academic purposes, I would still like to figure out what when wrong with my Barycentric Method.

Answer (score 1):

Your triangles are duplicated because you fully ignore the Z axis!

You do all your triangle math assuming 2D space and only using `Vector2`!

=> Of course you get a second triangle since on your round objects there will always be two triangles overlapping along the Z axis!

---

You will have to use an actual 3D "point in triangle" test like e.g. the one from [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/check-if-the-point-lies-inside-the-triangle.181524)

> ```
> bool PointInTriangle(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, Vector3 c, Vector3 p)
> {
>     Vector3 d, e;
>     double w1, w2;
>     d = b - a;
>     e = c - a;
>  
>     if (Mathf.Approximately(e.y, 0))
>     {
>         e.y = 0.0001f;
>     }
>      
>     w1 = (e.x * (a.y - p.y) + e.y * (p.x - a.x)) / (d.x * e.y - d.y * e.x);
>     w2 = (p.y - a.y - w1 * d.y) / e.y;
>     return (w1 >= 0f) && (w2 >= 0.0) && ((w1 + w2) <= 1.0);
> }
> ```

And then personally I would add some proper classes instead of arrays and do e.g.

```
public class SpecificTriangleIndex : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera m_camera;
    public LayerMask layermask;

    public class HitInfo
    {
        public Vector3 Point;
        public Triangle Triangle = new Triangle();
    }

    public class Triangle
    {
        public Vector3 A;
        public Vector3 B;
        public Vector3 C;

        public Vector3 Center => (A + B + C) / 3f;
    }

    private HitInfo currenHit;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Raycast();
        }
    }

    private void Raycast()
    {
        var ray = m_camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, float.PositiveInfinity, layermask))
        {
            var meshFilter = hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
            var mesh = meshFilter.sharedMesh;
            var vertices = mesh.vertices;
            var triangles = mesh.triangles;

            // Here you need to go into the local space of the hit not yourself!
            var p = hit.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point);

            for (var i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i += 3)
            {
                var a = vertices[triangles[i]];
                var b = vertices[triangles[i + 1]];
                var c = vertices[triangles[i + 2]];

                if (PointInTriangle(a, b, c, p))
                {
                    if (currenHit == null)
                    {
                        currenHit = new HitInfo();
                    }

                    currenHit.Point = hit.point;

                    // as before you also want to convert back using the hit transform, not your own
                    currenHit.Triangle.A = hit.transform.TransformPoint(a);
                    currenHit.Triangle.B = hit.transform.TransformPoint(b);
                    currenHit.Triangle.C = hit.transform.TransformPoint(c);

                    // we only want one triangle anyway so we can skip the remaining triangles
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            currenHit = null;
        }
    }

    private static bool PointInTriangle(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, Vector3 c, Vector3 p)
    {
        var d = b - a;
        var e = c - a;

        if (Mathf.Approximately(e.y, 0))
        {
            e.y = 0.0001f;
        }

        double w1 = (e.x * (a.y - p.y) + e.y * (p.x - a.x)) / (d.x * e.y - d.y * e.x);
        var w2 = (p.y - a.y - w1 * d.y) / e.y;
        return (w1 >= 0f) && (w2 >= 0.0) && ((w1 + w2) <= 1.0);
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        // only draw if there is a hit
        if (currenHit == null) return;

        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(currenHit.Point, .01f);

        Gizmos.color = Color.cyan;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(currenHit.Triangle.Center, .01f);

        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawLine(currenHit.Point, currenHit.Triangle.Center);

        Gizmos.color = Color.green;

        Gizmos.DrawLine(currenHit.Triangle.A, currenHit.Triangle.B);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(currenHit.Triangle.B, currenHit.Triangle.C);
        Gizmos.DrawLine(currenHit.Triangle.C, currenHit.Triangle.A);
    }
}
```

Maybe hard to see but this is how it looks like now

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to have fixed the problem. It works for about half the GameObject, with the other half still is [still malfunctioning](https://imgur.com/1R60Kn7). 

In fact, it is very similar to by [first attempt.](https://imgur.com/byyx3o3) before adding the array. 

Another interesting thing is if you [remove the break;, the "Correct" side flips](https://imgur.com/m4FiJ9P). That is very interesting, and I'm not entirely sure why.

But yeah, the problem still persists.

Comment: Your script did fix the "Dead Spots" between the two halves, so I thank you for that. It also improved the accuracy.

Comment: @FaffyWaffles hm maybe this implementation is still wrong on the Z axis .. I was already wondering why it only takes the x and y components into account :/ will try to find a better one